# DC power short circuit

Tags: dc-dc-converter, short-circuit

[image]

[image]

My DC adapter died. I checked it with the multimeter and got 0.

What I found is that the cable is short circuited. Testing the tip and testing the other end part of the cable both give continuity so I'm not sure if it is the cable or the jack.

I decided to open it up (first time doing it) now I think that maybe I should have tested the jack for continuity and if with continuity maybe cut the jack and test the cable before opening it up. I'm not sure but maybe it is the jack causing the problem.

I'm thinking to cut the jack and leaving it a bit of cable in cause it is not the problem to be able to solder it back.

Before I jump in and start messing with it even more when not needed, how would you approach this?

---

Thank you for clarifying. I was thinking it was AC to DC like most transformers here in the house, but now if I read this well its straight AC just controls the output voltage (nice I learned the purpose of those coiled boxes :)), like JRE said more then once, sorry I was in such a rush :).

So after reading and "thinking" if I did learned anything here I would say since this is just a transformer and transformers only work in AC, its very clear now that this is an AC adapter, for AC/DC would need a transformer and some rectifier or regulator as JRE stated in his/her first lines :).

To test the input coil for resistance do I need to desolder the cables?
In this test I didn't and I got nothing only 1.

Tested again with the multimeter since I used the wrong current first time, when I add the red lead gives me 6.7? And when I add the black lead goes to 02.

Wasn't it suppose to only give me a reading with both leads on it?

Thanks a lot for Replying JRE/Harper I am picking it by pieces but at least learning something.

[image: AC Adapter]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Welcome! Checked what with a multimeter? Voltage? Resistance? I don't see any rectification. Are you sure it's not just a transformer with AC output?

Comment: is it 0, or a few ohms? Because the secondary winding will measure as a near short naturally. As for how to handle this: Desolder the wires from the transformer so you can test them seperately.

Comment: thank you unimportant i will try that and see if it reads.  Yeah Winny my mistake it is AC.

Answer (score 4):

That is an AC adapter.  It puts out AC, not DC.

That is also the source of your "short circuit:"

[image]

The two wires I've circled in red are the AC input - they plug into the wall outlet in your house.

The two wires I've circled in blue are the output.  They come straight out of the transformer.  There's no AC/DC rectifier or regulator there.

A transformer coil is simply a bunch of wire wound on a metal core.  It will measure the same as a piece of wire - simply a very low resistance.

If your transformer has stopped working, the most likely causes are:

1. A broken wire in the primary side (line input) or in the secondary side (low voltage output.)
2. A blown fuse in the primary side.

You've already proven that there's no broken wire between the output and the plug - that's showing a very low resistance, just like it should.

Measure the resistance of the primary side.  That's between the blue and brown wires.

It should show a high resistance (hundreds or thousands of ohms) but it should not be completely open.  If the ohmmeter shows an open circuit, check from the plug pins (for the house outlet) to the wires inside the transformer.

One pin of the plug should be connected to the brown wire and one should be connected to the blue wire.

If the cable and the plug are OK, then all that is left is the fuse in the primary side.

That is not replaceable.  You would have to unwind the primary coil and replace the fusible link, then rewind the coil.

---

The simplest fix is to replace it.  Take it to an electronics shop and show them the little plate that has the input and output voltages marked on it and they will be able to find a replacement for it.

Comment: (Chances are `got 0` refers to a *DC* voltage measurement.)

Comment: @greybeard: "What I found is that the cable is short circuited. Testing the tip and testing the other end part of the cable both give continuity so I'm not sure if it is the cable or the jack."

Comment: thank you so much for replying, the cable that connects to the AC power is ok each sides have continuity, i will probably end up buying on for safety still i would love to learn more about it, what kinda of DC adapter is this one so i could search more about it, most i have seen have boards in it and not just the coil.

Comment: It is **NOT** a DC adapter.  It is clearly an AC adapter.  The output is AC.

Comment: Flip it over and make a picture of the side that gives the voltage ratings.  It almost certainly says that the output is AC.

Comment: ups my bad you are totally right, AC adaptar 12V 2.9 Amps, i will post it out of time atm, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the word "DC Adapter" to describe every lump-in-cord or wall-wart that plugs into the wall and gives a low voltage supply for use with gadgets.

That is incorrect and is the heart of your problem.

AC literally reverses polarity 100-120 times a second, this being an artifact of making electricity with spinning magnets instead of chemicals.  AC is easy to run through transformers, making it a "killer app" for building an electric grid.

As such, any pair of wires can have an AC or DC component *or both at once*.  A pure AC supply like that thing, will read 0 volts DC.  A pure DC supply like a car battery will read 0 volts AC.

Now, you had a way to know this.  The density of the unit.  DC switching power supplies are PC board, silicon, coil, empty space.  But this beast is solid copper and iron core, so it would be very dense for its size.   Being dense doesn't mean the output is AC - they might have a rectifier and smoothing cap inside - but it tells you they're using an old-guard transformer as the voltage conversion tech.

As JRE says, the winding of a transformer is very low impedance at a DC voltage (like your ohmmeter uses to measure). You can usually measure the primary for an "open". (measuring for a partial short is rather challenging).

On the DC - sorry, *the low voltage* side, if the output is AC you can probably do the same test. If the output is DC you'll be fighting a rectifier and caps, so meaningful readings are unlikely.

Comment: Thank you for replying.